# Python requests - get head response

Tags: python, python-requests, header

```
import requests
url = "https://freeuk14.listen2myradio.com/live.mp3?typeportmount=s1_31040_stream_97415691"
response = requests.head(url,stream=False,timeout=10)
```

Trying the above code i get timeout error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 104
, in head
    return request('head', url, **kwargs)
  File "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 61,
 in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", lin
e 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", lin
e 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", lin
e 529, in send
    raise ReadTimeout(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='freeuk14.listen2myrad
io.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=10)
```

But using https://httpstatus.io/ it return a response of text/html. Why? It's an mp3 audio stream.

What I am doing wrong about?

Comment: It didn't get the response within 10  seconds.

Comment: Ok, i try with a 60 seconds time window but the same error.

Comment: What are you trying to do ? See if the website answers ? Download the mp3 ?

Comment: either servers are down or very slow or your internet connection is unstable, the issue has nothing to do with your code

Comment: That url it's a radio mp3 stream. And i am trying to recognize it as radio stream. (Content-type=="audio/mpeg").

Comment: and if the stream is live then you might want to set stream=True and implement a block by block download system

Comment: I don't want to download it. Just to see the header response.

Comment: Note that is a head request.

Comment: This works fine and returns a HTTP 200 for me. `response.headers` prints the headers as well. Seemingly more a connection issue than a code issue.

Comment: @PacketLoss which is the content-type? audio/mpeg , text/html or something else?

Comment: `'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'`

Comment: For me still timeout error :\